# What to check when outlet detection is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I'm not sure what I did wrong, but I tried to connect the outlet from my main storyboard to my new `ViewControllerTableViewCell.swift` that I just created.

I set the **class** to `ViewControllerTableViewCell`

[image]

It contains

```
import UIKit

internal class ViewControllerTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    override internal func awakeFromNib()

    override internal func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
}
```

Now, I open up my `Main.storyboard` and attempting to drag my `image` and `label`

[image]

I did't see the auto detect come up.

However, when I tried to drag those into my `ViewController.swift`, it works.
To make sure it is not XCode Caching issue. I also restart my XCode, and still face same issue.

I was hoping to see something like this

[image]

How do I check further to make this work again?

Comment: Is the class of the cell in Storyboard correctly set to `ViewControllerTableViewCell` (ie the custom one you created)?

Comment: @Larme : How do I double check ? I update my post showing the class that I configured. Is it what you refering to ? Or Am I looking at the wrong class ?

Comment: xcode version? please

Comment: I don't do it your way, I always to the opposite. Could you check it works: Create the `@IBOutlet var someName: UIImageView!` in `ViewControllerTableViewCell`. Now, go on InterfaceBuilder, select your cell, on the left column select the last item (the one with an arrow in a circle: Connections Inspector), and check if "someName" appeared there and try to drag&drop until the image view.

Comment: @MAhipalSingh : I used XCode9, I also specified that as a tag on my question.

Comment: can you share your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. That's one of the disadvantages of using the interface building. But anyways, here's a solution:

1. Make sure that your custom tableView class, `ViewControllerTableViewCell` is assigned to your custom cell in your storyboard, like so:

[image]

2. Then, click on the **automatic** thing above, and see if you're viewing the cell class.
3. Try again now to have an outlet.

Also, CMD+B (building) helps the Xcode to correct some things.

[image]

Comment: I updated my post showing that I already have a **class** configured, what is the reason to re-assign another class? If you don't mind elaborate a bit on that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the custom tableCell class to the cell in IB

[image]

//

[image]

//

[image]

Comment: I updated my post showing that I already have a **class** configured, what is the reason to re-assign another class `ttTableViewCell` ? If you don't mind elaborate a bit on that.

Comment: I mean your class name , this is for an example , so assign **ViewControllerTableViewCell**

Comment: if it's not appeared in automatic menu try to look for it in manual , see edit